# Can modsecurity 2.x read data from a text file that has been updated?

Tags: mod-security

I'm writing a rule for modsecurity 2.x to match an IP address to those in a file.

```
 SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatchFromFile /etc/modsecurity/address_list.txt"
```

I understand how this works, I'm just wondering if anyone knows when modsecurity loads that .txt file.
Is it only loaded when the rules first load or can it be dynamically updated?

For instance, if you have a running instance of modsecurity on apache and you modify the address_list.txt file, will the rules pick that up or will you have to reload the apache config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files won't update dynamically in the server. If you want to get updated details, You need to restart the server. I checked this manually.